# IIS Certificate Request Wizard - installing a cert when not a domain admin

Tags: ssl, iis-6, certificate

We have a windows 2003 domain certificate authority internally that we use for SSL certificates. Domain admins are able to just use the IIS Certificate Request Wizard to install a certificate (choosing "Send the request immediately to an online certification authority" in the wizard).

When someone who is not a domain admin tries to do it they can complete the wizard and even ends up with a message saying it has installed the cert on the server. However, the cert is not installed.

Is there a specific permission that can be setup to allow a domain user who is not a domain admin to perform this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962096.aspx is what I was looking for.